# Find an item on a list from a number that is corresponding to the index of that item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Just making a small encryption program for fun and I've run into an issue. I've tried to google and view question **on** stackoverflow but it's either not here or I'm wording the question incorrectly and there is an actual term for this.

The problem is that I have a list, and I want to get an item from the list depending on a number I input. The number will correspond to the index of a specific item.

example:

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

item_selection = 4
```

That's all I really have. Essentially, the goal is to get item 4 off the list from the variable which would be item "e". Something similar to `my_list.index(item_selection)` (that doesn't work). Putting a raw number does not work either.

Comment: do you want `my_list[4]`? that would return `'e'`

Comment: ... Yes. I feel a bit silly now trying to figure out why is wasn't working but thank you lol.

Comment: Np :). The `list.index(n)` method is for finding the index of n. So `my_list.index('e')` would return `4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work: `print(my_list[item_selection])`

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by using the built in ability of index. Index's count up from 0, so list item four would actually be 3, "0,1,2,3" but if you wanted to deal with none zero numbers and then get the item, you could do this. Hope this helps, happy coding!!

```
my_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

item_selection = input("Input Item number: ")
item_selection = int(item_selection) - 1
print(f"{my_list[item_selection]}")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the extra information.

Comment: No problem! @goose.mp4